# What does "Agent Mulder's latest 302" mean?

Tags: meaning, numbers

The 4th episode of the *X-files* opens with:

> **FBI senior official:** Agent Mulder's latest 302. Requesting assignment and travel expenses for the both of you.
>
> **FBI Agent Scully:** Sioux city, Iowa. That's the first I've heard of it.

What does 302 refer to?

[Watch the episode online](https://www1.hdeuropix.io/tvseries/the-x-files-1993-online/the-x-files-1993-season-1-online-free-hd-streaming-europix)

Comment: 302 is probably the number of a form that must be submitted when seeking funds for travel on an assignment or something like that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about learning English. Better suited for Movies & TV SE.

Comment: @user3169 Well, an ELL can benefit from the fact that in English, forms can be referred to with a stand-alone number. I've just learned that.

Answer (score 3):

Agent Mulder is an FBI agent. A '302' is a specific numbered form used by the FBI.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FBI_forms#FD-302):

> A FD-302 form is used by FBI agents to "report or summarize the interviews that they conduct" and contains information from the notes taken during the interview by the non-primary agent.

Apparently, Agent Mulder regularly submits '302' forms to his seniors and the senior agent quoted is referring to his latest submission.